# Powershell help module not able to find help files in MacOS

Tags: powershell, helpfile, help-system

I am running PowerShell Core 7.2.6 installed via homebrew on MacBook Air M1 (12.6). However, when I try to use the help module to find some examples , I get this error.

```
REMARKS
Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It 
is displaying only partial help.
    -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes 
this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
    -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help 
Find-Module -Online" or
       go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398574.
```

I have tried to update the help module but no luck, same with uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Comment: What does “no luck” mean? Do you get errors?

Comment: I don't know if MacOS has the same concept (I'm a Windows guy), but on Windows, in order to update the help files, you need to open Powershell as an "elevated" session, or "Run as Administrator", then do the `Update-Help`. You might also be able to view the complete help information with `Get-Help -Online «cmd»`

Comment: @DougMaurer , says updating help module for Microsoft.Powershell...[Locating help content..]

But after that its still the same result when I run the help command.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  thanks jeff for your input. I did try from the "sudo" command but for some reason still not updating the help module. And yes, I am aware that I can find the commands help in Microsoft docs but just wanted to find the root cause of this bug.

Answer (score 3):

Note: See [Sotiris's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75493250/45375) for the potential need to use `-UICulture en-US`, and for specifics on how the `PowerShellGet` module's help is broken.

---

It is implied by the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) error message you're seeing, but to spell it out in more detail:

- The command you're trying to invoke help for is a cmdlet and therefore part of a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules).
- That module's [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) defines an online help source, via its `HelpInfoURI` entry, but no local (offline) help content has ever been downloaded.

  - This is typical for the *built-in* modules that come with [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the only edition available on non-Windows platforms such as macOS.
  - It can conceivably also happen with *third-party* modules, although the ones available via the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) and installed via [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module) usually come *bundled* with their offline help content.

As the error message suggests, [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help) must be used to download such help content on demand; see the next section for details and general troubleshooting tips.

However, the problem in your *specific* case - trying to invoke local help for the `Find-Module` cmdlet - is that  **the downloadable help content for the specific [`PowerShellGet` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget) that the `Find-Module` cmdlet is a part of appears to be broken as of this writing.**

If you run the following command, you'll see that `Update-Help` *downloads* help content, but it seemingly *isn't recognized*; that is, running `Update-Help` makes no effective difference.

```
# Output shows that the following file is updated:
#  $HOME/.local/share/powershell/Help/PowerShellGet/en-US/PSModule-help.xml
Update-Help -Force -Verbose -Module PowerShellGet
```

Therefore:

- I encourage you to report an issue in [`PowerShellGet`'s GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues).
- As a workaround - assuming you're connected to the internet - use the `-Online` switch for now so as to open the help content in your default web browser (you cannot directly pass `-Examples` then, but just click the "Examples" link on the right-hand side to jump to the examples section).

---

#### Using and troubleshooting `Update-Help`:

- Note that there is no help *module* as such (it sounds like you meant  the `help` *command*, which is a function wrapper around `Get-Help` that provides *interactive paging* of long output from the latter). There's the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) cmdlet that is part of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core` module, and there's  downloaded help *content*, which you may have to download on demand via **[`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help)**:

  - `Update-Help` without a `-Scope` argument in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* defaults to `-Scope CurrentUser`, which means that the help content is downloaded to a user-specific location.
  - With `-Scope AllUsers` (the default in *Windows PowerShell*, where no `-Scope` parameter exists), you need to run **with elevation (as admin) on Windows**, and via **`sudo powershell` on macOS and Linux.**
  - **Use `-Force` to ensure that content is always downloaded**, if available. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help), `-Force` bypasses two built-in constraints: permitting only a single run *per day*, and limiting the download data volume to 1GB (though exceeding that seems unlikely).
  - Add **`-Verbose`** to get details about the operations performed by `Update-Help`, which includes the modules targeted and their online source URLs, as well as whether updated content was found and downloaded.
  - You can also limit `Update-Help` to **updating the help for (a) *given module(s)* (`-Module`)** and/or **specific *cultures* (human languages) (`-UICulture`)**.

    - To learn the name of a module that a given command is part of, if any, use the following, using `Get-Content` as an example: `(Get-Command Get-Content).Module.Name`; note that you must use the actual command name, not an alias for it (such as `gc`); for an alias, use something like `(Get-Command gc).ResolvedCommand.Module.Name`
    - By default, content matching the *current* UI culture (as reflected in `$PSUICulture`) is downloaded; if no such content is available, but the content is available for *other* UI cultures, the resulting error message will list those.
- However, even then it isn't guaranteed that help becomes available for *all* commands available in your session, given that implementing command-line help is optional (though recommended).

  - If there's no error message when you run `Update-Help -Force` yet no help content becomes available, the implication is that no online source for a module that a given command is part of, if any, is defined.

    - However, if you target such a module *explicitly* with `-Module`, the absence of an online source *does* result in an error to that effect.
    - It is the `HelpInfoURI` entry in a module's [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) that defines an online help source.
  - If an online source is defined, but not reachable / doesn't have the expected content, you'll get an error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and, asking in PowerShell's discord server, the answer turned out to be that there wasn't any documentation available for my culture. Doing

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US -Force
```

solved the problem by downloading the documentation for the en-US culture.

However, as mklement0 mentioned in his answer, the help for this particular module seems to be broken. Looking into PowerShellGet files, the module uses different names for the module (PowerShellGet), and the file containing the code (PSModule.psm1). Although, this shouldn't be a problem, as the module uses the #.ExternalHelp directive for [function help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/help/naming-help-files?view=powershell-7.3#function-help-files) which doesn't have any specific naming requirements, it seems it doesn't work correctly.

A quick fix for this that apparently works is to change the name of the help file from 'PSModule-help.xml' to 'PowerShellGet-help.xml'. This file is under

```
$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Help\PowerShellGet\en-US
```

for Windows systems, or

```
$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Help/PowerShellGet/en-US
```

for non-Windows systems.

Note, that even if you do this, you won't be able to get help for Get-CredsFromCredentialProvider as it is missing from the .xml help file. However, this is an internal function that wasn't meant to be exported in the first place, so the missing documentation is actually [deliberate](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5383#issuecomment-606259961). Still, if you want to check out what it was, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/e5f400313444e97d12b7d97e703be3448d350c5b/reference/7.1/PowerShellGet/Get-CredsFromCredentialProvider.md) (though there's not any interesting content whatsoever :) )!

Comment: Hi Sotiris, I believe the PowerShellGet team has fixed this. I did raise an issue on their github repo regarding this. They guided me saying that the command is slightly different in the PS7 but I believe this normal command "get-help find-module -Examples" is also working now. :) 
Thanks for your input though, really appreciate it. :)