# powershell gh command fails after running update-hlp

Tags: powershell

somewhat new to Powershell and trying to use get-help about-scripts or any about command and all update-help is failing with this error..

```
update-help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender, ConfigDefenderPerformance, DefenderPerformance, Dism, Get-NetView, Kds, NetQos, PcsvDevice, Pester, PKI, StorageBusCache, VMDirectStorage, Whea, WindowsUpdate' with UI culture(s) {en-US} :
Unable to retrieve the HelpInfo XML file for UI culture en-US. Make sure the HelpInfoUri property in the module manifest is valid or check your network connection and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-help

update-help about-scripts fails with this error:

get-help : Get-Help could not find about-scripts in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help about-scripts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

Any thoughts or suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

In powershell 5.1 on windows 11 tried get-help about-scripts and got message

```
get-help : Get-Help could not find about-scripts in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help about-scripts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

Tried to run update-help and got

```
update-help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender, ConfigDefenderPerformance, DefenderPerformance, Dism, Get-NetView, Kds, NetQos, PcsvDevice, Pester, PKI, StorageBusCache, VMDirectStorage, Whea, WindowsUpdate' with UI culture(s) {en-US} :
Unable to retrieve the HelpInfo XML file for UI culture en-US. Make sure the HelpInfoUri property in the module manifest is valid or check your network connection and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToRetrieveHelpInfoXml,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're looking for the conceptual [about_Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scripts) help topic, which you misspelled as `about-scripts` (`-` rather than `_`).

  - Note that you can use *wildcards* with `Get-Help` / `help`, so you could have discovered the correct title with `Get-Help *scripts*`, for instance (if there's only *one* match, that matching topic is instantly displayed; otherwise, you'll get a *list* of  matching topics).
- Conceptual help topics (those titled `about_*`) cannot be updated separately, [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help) expects the name of one or more installed *modules* instead (and the help for those modules may *include* `about_*` topics).
- `Update-Help` can fail, if the targeted modules either have no links to  downloadable online help sources associated with them, or if those links are no longer valid.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829097/45375) for additional information about `Update-Help`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and respond.  Both your suggestions were helpful.  Tried about_scripts and that returned help on scripts.